# GitLab API: Deleting repository tags in bulk does not delete images

Tags: gitlab, docker-registry, gitlab-api

The GitLab API docs show how to [delete images/tags by given tag or in bulk](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/container_registry.html#delete-a-repository-tag). Deleting a single tag works fine, but deleting in bulk only returns "202" and nothing seems to happen.

Deleting a single tag works fine, return code is "200"

```
curl --request DELETE --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <.....>" "https://gitlab.example.net/api/v4/projects/development%2Ffoo%2Fbar/registry/repositories/11/tags/20190704T130204"
```

Deleting in bulk does not seem to do anything. Return code is "202", no further information can be found in the response body

```
curl --request DELETE --data "name_regex=.*" --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <.....>" "https://gitlab.example.net/api/v4/projects/development%2Ffoo%2Fbar/registry/repositories/11/tags"
```